# Size of audit logs site collection

Tags: 2013, auditing

I have recently enabled the site audit feature.  The logs are trimmed automatically after 30 days.  How can I check how much room this taking up?  Where is the info stored?

Answer (score 2):

You can use T-SQL on the Content Database.

`Use [ContentDbName]
EXEC sp_spaceused AuditData`

As far as I'm aware, there is no SSOM to expose *just* storage used by Audit data.